# Значения каждой цифры при изменении версии

Tags: версионность

При выпуске новых версий ПО, разработчики присваивают продукту новый номер версии.

Так вот, например, есть версия **1.8.3**, при следующем апдейте могу присвоить *1.8.4*, либо *1.9.0*, либо *2.0.0* - отчего будет зависеть какой номер присвоят следующий?

Comment: Дело вкуса и внутренних правил. Есть minor changes (младшие цифры), есть major changes (старшая цифра). Обычно при введении большого количества новых функций, увеличивают major. Но правил четких нет. В php после 5.6 сразу вышла 7.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Интересный способ версионного контроля : x.xy.xyz

Можно закодировать полезную информацию...

Например, в чем отличия ПО v.1.2.54 от ПО v.1.3.60

> x - Глобальные изменения (возможно даже нет обратной совместимости, в данном примере нет изменений)
>   xy - Расширен функционал (например, добавлен 1 отчет)
>   xyz - Bug Fix (в данном случае было исправлено 6 багов)